# Cannot remove variable because it has been optimized and is not removable - releasing a COM object

Tags: powershell, com

At the end of my script I use `'ie' | ForEach-Object {Remove-Variable $_ -Force}`. It works fine in PS 2 (Windows 7) but PS 5 (Windows 10) throws an error:

> Cannot remove variable ie because the variable has been optimized and
>   is not removable. Try using the Remove-Variable cmdlet (without any
>   aliases), or dot-sourcing the command that you are using to remove the
>   variable.

How can I make it play nice with PS 5; or should I just use `Remove-Variable 'ie' -Force`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The recommended way to remove COM objects is to call the ReleaseComObject method, passing the object reference ($ie) to the instance of your COM object.

Here is more detailed explanation and sample code from a [Windows PowerShell Tip of the Week](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730962.aspx) that shows how to get rid of COM objects:

> Whenever you call a COM object from the common language runtime (which
>   happens to be the very thing you do when you call a COM object from
>   Windows PowerShell), that COM object is wrapped in a “runtime callable
>   wrapper,” and a reference count is incremented; that reference count
>   helps the CLR (common language runtime) keep track of which COM
>   objects are running, as well as how many COM objects are running. When
>   you start Excel from within Windows PowerShell, Excel gets packaged up
>   in a runtime callable wrapper, and the reference count is incremented
>   to 1.
>
> That’s fine, except for one thing: when you call the Quit method and
>   terminate Excel, the CLR’s reference count does not get decremented
>   (that is, it doesn’t get reset back to 0). And because the reference
>   count is not 0, the CLR maintains its hold on the COM object: among
>   other things, that means that our object reference ($x) is still valid
>   and that the Excel.exe process continues to run. And that’s definitely
>   not a good thing; after all, if we wanted Excel to keep running we
>   probably wouldn’t have called the Quit method in the first place.  ...
>
> ... calling the ReleaseComObject method [with] our
>   instance of Excel ... decrements the reference count for the object in
>   question. In this case, that means it’s going to change the reference
>   count for our instance of Excel from 1 to 0. And that is a good thing:
>   once the reference count reaches 0 the CLR releases its hold on the
>   object and the process terminates. (And this time it really does
>   terminate.)
>
> ```
> $x = New-Object -com Excel.Application
> $x.Visible = $True
> Start-Sleep 5
> $x.Quit()
> [System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($x)
> Remove-Variable x
> ```

The message "Cannot remove variable ie because the variable has been optimized and is not removable." you get, most likely means you have tried to access (inspect, watch, or otherwise access) a variable which has been already removed by the optimizer.

Answer (score 2):

[wp78de's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8291949/wp78de) explains what you need to do to *effectively* release a COM object instantiated in PowerShell code with `New-Object -ComObject`.

Releasing the underlying COM object (which means terminating the process of a COM automation server such as Internet Explorer) is what matters most, but it's worth pointing out that:

- Even without calling `[System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($ie)` first, there's NO reason why your `Remove-Variable` call should fail (even though, if successful, it wouldn't by itself release the COM object).

  - I have no explanation for the error you're seeing (I cannot recreate it, but it may be related to [this bug](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/4312)).
- There's usually no good reason to use `ForEach-Object` with `Remove-Variable`, because you can not only pass *one* variable name directly, but even an *array* of names to the (implied) `-Name` parameter - see `Remove-Variable -?`;
  `Remove-Variable ie -Force` should work.
- Generally, note that `-Force` is only needed to remove *read-only* variables; if you want to (also) guard against the case where a variable by the specified name(s) doesn't *exist*, (also) use
  `-ErrorAction Ignore`.