# Can't insert formula referencing different worksheet using Powershell

Tags: excel, powershell, excel-formula, excel-2010, cell

For some reason, inserting formula into Excel table using Powershell script. If formula is entered manually, it works fine. Suppose I have 3 elements in `$names` array:

```
$excel = New-Object -ComObject excel.application 
$excel.visible = $true
$workbook = $excel.Workbooks.Add()

$names = @()
foreach ($i in 1,2,3) {
  $ws = $workbook.Worksheets.Add()
  $names += $ws.Name
}

$i = 1
foreach ($sheet in $names) {
  $formula = "=COUNT('$sheet'!D:D)"
  write-host $formula
  $excel.cells.item($i, 1).Formula = $formula
  $i++
}
```

What happens: The first cell gets the correct value, but the formula name is missing (e.g. instead of `=COUNT('Sheet2'!D:D)` I get `=('Sheet2'!D:D)`, and the other 2 throw `0x800A03EC` exception. The sheet I reference definitely exists, because if I copy and paste values printed by `write-host $formula` manually, it works as expected.

It also seems to work correctly If I don't reference another sheet. The code below doesn't throw any exceptions:

```
$formula = "=COUNT(D:D)"
$excel.cells.item($i, 1).Formula = $formula
```

**UPDATE:**

Seems like an issue specific to Excel 2010. In Excel 2016, the same code works fine.

Comment: That code works just fine for me, must be something with your Office version.

Comment: Was the contribution helpful to you?

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to mock your approach and came up with the following working code:

```
foreach($ws in $b.Sheets) {
  $ws.Cells.Item(1,1).Formula = "=COUNT($($ws.Name)!D:D)"
}
```

Comment: Note: take care to remove the COM object properly: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46269778/8291949

Comment: in this code, you don't reference a different sheet in the formula, which works fine for me. I only run into problems when formula contains a sheet reference. Also, note that first and second formula insertions may have different results, which is why I used loop.

Comment: I've tried your code, and got the exact same problems that I was encountering: 1st insertion removes function name (`=(Sheet1!D:D)` instead of `=COUNT(Sheet1!D:D)`), 2nd and 3rd insertions result in `#NAME?` error, even though function seems correct.

Comment: As I said, I have exact same problems with my version, so this probably isn't it. I honestly have no idea at this point. Everything looks correct, it just doesn't work.

Comment: What version of Office do you use? I use 2016.

Comment: I have updated question to include complete example. I have also tried to use a loop from your example. I currently use Office 2010.

Comment: I've tried it in Excel 2016, and it works. I guess it's a bug in Excel 2010?

Comment: Indeed. But I have no idea how to fix this. Do you have the latest patches applied to O2010? That's all.

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to make it work using `FormulaLocal` instead of `Formula`. I still believe it's a bug in Excel 2010, since `Formula` works perfectly fine in Excel 2016. I also still can't insert array formulas containing sheet references in Excel 2010 from script: even assigning `FormulaLocal` first, and then assigning it's value to `FormulaArray` doesn't work.