# Using 'Item' for spreadsheets in powershell v2.0

Tags: excel, powershell

If possible can someone point me in the right direction? I'm almost done with a script that will allow me to generate a prefilled spreadsheet based on information from the user. The only issue I'm having is how to copy one worksheet from an existing workbook to the new workbook.

I have a 'DATA' sheet with the names of worksheets that correspond to a second workbook. I want PowerShell to read the cells, then use those read names to pull worksheets with each corresponding name. Currently I'm running into an indexing error when I try to use the following below (just an example):

```
$dog = "UPS"
$sourceSheet = $sourceSheets.Item($dog)
```

Can PS open worksheet cells by name using "Item"?

```
    #This reads the 'DATA' sheet and uses the numbers to figure out what kits are being used for each UTC
$count = 0
For ($k = 2; $k -le 25; $k++)
 {
     $Value += $datasheet.Cells.Item(1, $k).Text
     #next two lines verify number of cells 
     If ($Value -ne "") {$count++}
     Write-Host $count
 }
#Creates name for excel spreadsheet
$cutsheet = "cutsheet"

#saves spreadsheet in folder created earlier
$worksheet.SaveAs("Q:\$mission\$cutsheet")

#opens inventory workbook
$source = $excel.workbooks.Open("Q:\inventory.xlsx")

$sourceSheets = $source.Worksheets
$sourceSheet = $sourceSheets.Item(2)
$dest2 = $worksheets.Item(7)
$sourceSheet.copy($dest2)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried to mock your scenario and came up with the following code:

```
$excel = New-Object -comobject Excel.Application
$excel.Visible = $True
#opens inventory workbook
$source = $excel.workbooks.Open("C:\Users\you\Desktop\test.xls")
$dest = $excel.workbooks.Open("C:\Users\you\Desktop\a.xls")

$source.Worksheets.Item(2).copy($dest.Worksheets.Item(2))
$dest.Save()
$excel.Quit()
```

Comment: Note: take care to remove the COM object properly: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46269778/8291949