# Unable to check InternetExplorer.Application ComObject properties after calling Navigate

Tags: .net, powershell, comobject

I have an annoying issue where I can't get any properties about an `InternetExplorer.Application` `ComObject` after calling `Navigate`:

```
$ie = new-object -com InternetExplorer.Application
$ie.navigate("https://the.url")
$ie.visible = $true
while ($ie.ReadyState -ne 4) { start-sleep -m 100; Write-Host $ie.ReadyState }
```

The script gets stuck in the `while` loop and outputs nothing to the console for `ReadyState`.

Stepping through the code in ISE, I can see that before `Navigate` is called, all the properties are available and `ReadyState` contains a value of `0`, however as soon as `Navigate` gets called there are no longer any properties to be found in `$ie`.

What is going on here? I am pretty sure I've used this code before, but maybe I am missing something?

Comment: Does this happen on all the urls or just specific a web page?

Comment: Does this only happen on https pages and not http?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's because you have IE open before? The following code works for as expected for me: It checks if there is already an Internet Explorer instance, creates a new one if not, runs your code and quits.

```
$ie = $null
$newInstance = $false
if (Get-Process iexplore -ea silentlycontinue | Where-Object {$_.MainWindowTitle -ne ""}) {
    $ie = (New-Object -COM "Shell.Application").Windows() | ? { $_.Name -eq "Internet Explorer" } | Select-Object -First 1
    sleep -milliseconds 500
    $ie.visible = $true
    $newInstance = $false
} else {
    $ie = New-Object -COM "InternetExplorer.Application"
    sleep -milliseconds 500
    $ie.visible = $true
    $newInstance = $true
}

$ie.Navigate("www.bing.com");

Write-Host $ie.ReadyState
while ($ie.ReadyState -ne 4) {
    start-sleep -m 100; Write-Host $ie.ReadyState
}

$ie.Quit()
[System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($ie)
Remove-Variable ie
```

<sub>PS: Always [release COM objects properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46269051/cannot-remove-variable-because-it-has-been-optimized-and-is-not-removable-rele/46269778#46269778) afterwards.</sub>